# Menu key not working in AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have been porting Material to an open sourced app. I have used the AppCompat v21 library. I hit the menu key and I get nothing. Everything else works.

What am I doing wrong? I will attach code later as I am sending this from my phone.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_view_source" android:title="@string/action_view_source"  />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_view_translation" android:title="@string/action_view_translation" yourapp:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_view_bugs" android:title="@string/action_view_bugs" yourapp:showAsAction="never"  />
</menu>
```

Java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
  …
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It appears that the Menu key was disabled in the new AppCompat. I actually found a way to fix it and I guess I will share it with you.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
...
setContentView(R.layout.main);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar.isOverflowMenuShowing()) {
            toolbar.dismissPopupMenus();
        } else {
            toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```